# sharepoint and Jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, web-parts

I have a web-part on my SharePoint page which contains some HTML and a couple of JavaScript plugins.

Now while editing this page all works, I read up on how to handle the conflict with JQuery and below is what I have come up with. However, it still does not work when I save and view the page because my Jquery plugin never get initialize.

```
 <script src="../master_page_items/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../master_page_items/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="../master_page_items/picture_slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://c64.assets-yammer.com/assets/platform_embed.js"></script>

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("init");

function init()
{

jQuery("#slider").easySlider({
        auto: true,
        continuous: true,
                pause:5000,
                prevText: '',
        nextText: ''
    });


    jQuery('.nav li').hover(
      function () { //appearing on hover
        jQuery('ul', this).fadeIn();
      },
      function () { //disappearing on hover
       jQuery('ul', this).fadeOut();
      }
    );


  yam.connect.embedFeed(
      { 
         container: '#customright',
        network: 'aon.com'
  });   
}


</script
```

>

I'm not sure what else I'm missing or am I doing this correctly?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have mentioned correct file paths for Jquery and handled conflicts correctly, first try with small example see if it works.

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("myFunctionName");
function myCustomName(){
 alert('a');
}
```

If above code is alerting out "a" then your jquery references are correct and _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push() is functioning correctly.

You can try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myCustomName, "sp.js");
});
```

I hope Values used in image slider are already present on page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with the ".." in your path to the jquery files.  I can't try it right now, but typically I use a server-relative URL to reference my jquery files.  That way you can put the web part on any page in the site an still reference it.  so something like /sites/MySite/MySubsite/master_page_files/jquery-2.2.0.min.js

In addition to what Vaibhav said, I'd also just try:

```
JQuery(document).ready(function(){
    alert('b');
});
```

to make sure JQuery loaded and take SP out of the mix altogether.